# Type "name" in "path" is part of the declarations of 2 modules: Error while building an Ionic 4 project

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, build, ionic4

I tried to build my Ionic app with the commands:

> ionic cordova platform add browser

and then

> ionic cordova build browser --prod --release

but there was this weird error: https://prnt.sc/pf58hd

Github link to my project: https://github.com/TenPetr/to_do_list

Angular version: **8.1.2**

Ionic version: **4.7.1**

Thanks for your advices.

Answer (score 0):

The error is very clear you have declared  **`AddNewLabelsPage`** in two modules such as 
**`AppModule`** and **`AddNewLabelsPageModule`**

Remove the declaration from AppModule, but update the AppModule configuration to import your AddNewLabelsPageModule.

Your app.module should look like,

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DoneAllPage,
    SettingsPage
  ],
  entryComponents: [AddNewTaskPage, DoneAllPage, SettingsPage],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
    AddNewTaskPageModule
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    TimeDateService,
    TasksService,
    LabelsService,
    SettingsService,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I dont know if I did this correctly... I still gets errors.. this is my app.module - https://prnt.sc/pf5fn4 and this is the error: https://prnt.sc/pf5fu6

Comment: now the error is different, you need to remove AddNewLabelsPageModule from the entry component

Comment: wich repo do you mean please?

Comment: your github repository

Comment: Yes, now its up to date

Comment: In the imports, shouldnt there be AddNewLabelsPageModule insted of AddNewTaskPageModule?

Comment: whatever the modules you have in your app needs to be there

Comment: can you please check the code i posted , it works fine

Comment: I dont know why, but I still gets these errors over and over again

Comment: restart your app and see, thats all i can say